# Changing JAXB unmarshalling as per the ORM structure

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am receiving following XML structure:

```
<Parent>
    <Holding id="111"/>
    <Party id="yyy"/>
    <Party id="xxx"/>
    <Party id="zzz"/>
    <Relation partyRefId="xxx" holdingRefId="111"/>
    <Relation partyRefId="yyy" holdingRefId="111"/>
</Parent>
```

XML will be unmarshall to object model with the help of JAXB and I am saving it into the database using hibernate. So there is table for each element and column for each attribute.
 Here Relation table has
HoldingFK and PartyFK columns. In this
`if Relation.holdingRefId == Holding.id` 
then Relation.HoldingFK is going to have database genearted HoldingPK and same will be applicable to Party too.
`if Relation.partyRefId ==Party.id` then Relation.PartyFk will have database specific PartyPK value.
Now JAXB is naturally creating an child array of Relation objects which can only have ParentFKs if persisted into database.
How can I add Relation objects as children of Holding or Party based on some condition?

```
Note: Here I have actual business terminology to make my query more understandable.
```

Comment: Why to fiddle with regular unmarshalling? You need a transformation layer that converts/adjusts the unmarshalled objects into the model expected by ORM.

Comment: @Pangea Currently I am using afterUnmarshall() method to do the transformation. Wishing If JAXB can provide something out of the box.

Comment: There is no out of the box support. However, the implementations like Moxy provides "extensions" that enable you to marshall the XML to any domain model you want.

Comment: @Pangea I am already using Moxy API for some other functionality. Can you please point me to a similar "extensions" example.

Comment: Check the XPath based mapping: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: @Pangea I am not sure if it will work for me because here I need at 3 positions. Under Parent, under Holding and under Party.